# How to get a granite counter top with sink off a wooden bathroom vanity

Tags: bathroom, sink, removal, countertops, vanity

I have a standard 37" x 22" granite top with sink on top of a typical bathroom vanity. The sink is cracked and a corner on the top is knocked off. I've found many tops with sink available that will fit perfectly, but I do not know how to get the old top off. I have of course tried to pull up but it's stuck on there so that didn't work. There are no screws or bolts holding it either. Since i want to preserve the vanity I can't just pry it off with some sort of crowbar.  Anyone got good ideas in this regard or do I have to replace the vanity also?

Comment: Pictures should help.

Answer (score 4):

Use a long sharp knife, like a carpet/flooring knife, to slice through the caulking or construction adhesive that was used on the top of the vanity when the sink was set onto it. Then yes, use a lifting/prying strategy that minimizes potential for damage to the cabinet. You may need to slice, lift a little, slice some more, lift a little more, slice...

Comment: If the counter doesn't have a lip, a Sawzall™ type saw, weilded carefully, should cut right through. It may take a sliver off the top of the cabinet, in addition to cutting the adhesive, but nobody would notice the 1/16" or so missing.

Comment: Oscillating saw !

Comment: Actually yes, this would be the perfect application for one of them newfangled oscillating saws. I have always wondered whether or not I would use one often enough to justify buying... I think I need one... more tools = happiness.

Answer (score 3):

Since the old sink is cracked just use a sledge hammer to break it into small pieces which can then easily be levered off the glue joints.

Comment: Wear eye protection when smashing ceramic. Or face. I got lots of little cuts on my face once doing this.

Answer (score 3):

After you've undone the plumbing below, I'd use quick support rods or 2x4s cut a little long to push up on the bottom of the sink and help to lift it out.  While the quick rods are pushing up use a long knife and slice any silicone that is holding the sink to the counter.

If you use the quick support rod then you can just turn the rod to increase the force applied.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y74yDYljQO8

Comment: What is a "quick rod"? Pics or link would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you guys! I used all the advice and got the top out without any damage to the vanity. What took a lot of time was cutting the glue or whatever it is) around the edges. I used a serrated long knife in the end and a wooden wedge to keep the gap. That took hours so I did it over a few days. Anyhow, thank you again for help! I do not think I would have attempted it without the encouragement and advice I got here.